# Fill down based on top column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like so:

```
ID   Value
1     A
2     B
3     X
3     Y
3     Y
3     D
4     C
5     C
```

For every instance of a repeated ID, where the top value is X and corresponding values are Y, I want to fill down with X. 
The resulting set is like so:

```
ID   Value
1     A
2     B
3     X
3     X
3     X
3     D
4     C
5     C
```

I have tried to mask and fill down like so:

```
df['Value']= df.Value.mask(~df.Value.isin(['X', 'Y'])).ffill()
```

The above does not work as intended.

Comment: Why is there a D in the third row from the bottom? Shouldn't it be an X?

Comment: It is a D since not all values in the group are X - some are different and only the X's must be filled in

Comment: so the goal is to replace only if the id is repeated and the value is 'Y'?

Comment: Yuca - that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do with `mask` + `np.where`

```
s1=df.Value.mask(df.Value=='Y').groupby(df['ID']).ffill()
df.Value=np.where((s1!=df.Value)&(s1=='X'),s1,df.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
edict = df.groupby('ID').Value.first().to_dict())
temp = df[(df.ID.isin(idx)) & (df.Value == 'Y')].ID.values
df.loc[(df.ID.isin(idx)) & (df.Value == 'Y'), 'Value'] = [edict[x] for x in temp]
```

Output:

```
   ID Value
0   1     A
1   2     B
2   3     X
3   3     X
4   3     X
5   3     D
6   4     C
7   5     C
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the prettiest solution, but at least it gets the job done:
`df.loc[(df.id.isin(df[df.val=="X"].id.unique())) & (df.val=="Y"), "val"] = "X"`

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution using [`np.where()`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`pd.series.duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df['ID_duplicated']=df.ID.duplicated()
cond = (df.ID_duplicated==True ) & (df.Value=='Y')
df.Value = np.where(cond,'X',df.Value)
>>df
    ID  Value   ID_duplicated
0   1   A       False
1   2   B       False
2   3   X       False
3   3   X       True
4   3   X       True
5   3   D       True
6   4   C       False
7   5   C       False
```